# form validation in zf2 using phpunit

Tags: zend-framework2, phpunit

I am trying to write a PHPunit test for form post that is  written in ZF2. The Action that I want to test is follows,

```
public function resetAction() {
    try {
        $resetForm = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Login\Model\ResetForm');
        $message = $errmessage = null;
        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $resetForm->setInputFilter($resetForm->getInputFilter());
            $resetForm->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            if ($resetForm->isValid()) {
                $signInService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Login\Model\SignInService');
                /* Genereate a unique token to put to the tAccounts table to reset the password */
                $serverUrl = $this->getRequest()->getUri()->getScheme() . '://' . $this->getRequest()->getUri()->getHost();
                /* Complete the URL, this need to change */
                $serverUrl = $serverUrl . '/basezf2/public';
                /* Initiate the reset password send email notification process */
                if ($signInService->sendPasswordResetNotification($resetForm->getData(), $serverUrl)) {
                    $message = 'Email has been send with the password reset link';
                } else {
                    $errmessage = 'No account found for given email address';
                }
            }
        }
        return new ViewModel(array('resetForm' => $resetForm, 'message' => $message, 'errmessage' => $errmessage));
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $log = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Error\Log');
        $log->log(Logger::ERR, $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

My unite test as follows

```
public function testresetActionPost() {
    date_default_timezone_set('US/Eastern');
    $this->dispatch('/login/reset', 'POST', array('email' => 'notEmail'));
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
}
```

This test as you see I am not sending the proper email address and when I do this via web, the form validation fails and do everything it suppose to do. How can I get that work within my test.

I am using `Zf2` + `PHPunit 3.7`.

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. Doesn't the test fail? Don't you know how to detect the validation failure? What are you expecting, what is happening instead?

Comment: Yes I need to know how to detect the validations.

Comment: What are you expecting, what is happening instead?

Comment: in both cases it I get the 200 response (with valid and invalid email). What I want is, when I try the test with invalid email, test should tell me the validation fails. when I use the UI and when validation fails, I get the proper messages from the framework.